# addcontentsline works for section but not for chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I'm trying to add a new chapter to both the bookmarks in the PDF as well as the table of contents, without having the chapter appear on the page outside of the TOC.  When I try this using `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter Title Here}`, it gets an error and won't compile.  Here's the code that errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}

\section{First Section}

\end{document}
```

Interestingly, when I change chapter to section and section to subsection, everything works as I want, except that I want these to be at the chapter and section levels instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter 1}

\subsection{First Section}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix the top example so that it works like the second example but with the desired levels?

Comment: You are aware there is no chapter support in article? there's no `\chatpter` command and thus of course no support for formatting chapters in the toc. Please use a document class that supports chapters.

Comment: ... for example, `report` or `book` classes.

Comment: Or, as you  load `titlesec`, you can create  `\chapter` as a new sectional level for the article class, between `part` and `\section`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard [`article` class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) does not support the use of `\chapter`s. Separation of `\section`s is typically achieved by using `\part`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Chapter 1}

\section{First Section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
 \makeatletter
 \let\l@chapter\l@section
 \let\l@section\l@subsection
 \let\l@subsection\l@subsubsection
 \makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}

\section{First Section}

\end{document}
```